# How to reverse the arrows in a Digraph using networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to reverse the arrows of a Digraph, making the second column to be the parent. I am trying to use the nx.Digraph.reverse() method of networkx but it is giving me an error of TypeError: reverse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. How can I make second column to be the parent node when there also has an attribute  for the To value and a dictionary cannot hold the same key value so I cannot simply interchange the keys of the dictionary.

This is my code:

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(train, 'To', 'From',create_using=nx.DiGraph.reverse())
```

My dataframe is:

```
To    |    From   |  Category
A     |     A     |    0
B     |     A     |    0
C     |     A     |    0
D     |     F     |    1
E     |     F     |    1
```

The category is for the 'To' column. But when I try to use the Digraph it shows the 'To' value converging to the 'From' value. I want to make it such that it is diverging away from the 'From' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nx.DiGraph.reverse()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.reverse.html) is expecting an instance of a graph. Instead set `create_using` to `nx.DiGraph()` to create directed graph from the edges of the dataframe and *then* reverse the direction of the edges:

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'To', 'From', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

Now by doing as mentioned above:

```
G_rev = nx.DiGraph.reverse(G)
nx.draw(G_rev)
```

[image]

Comment: with `draw_networkx_edges` you can also pass the reversed edges in the `edgelist` argument